# Possible to displace whole polygons only, not points

Tags: displacement

I want to have displacement to complete polygons, not single points. Rightnow displacement in Blender affects points.

I have the polygons separated inside the mesh and want them to move up and down depending on the displacement map, but each individual polygon should remain flat.

Is it possible to displace in "polygon mode"?

Thanks.

Comment: In order to displace or move a polygon without changing other vertices, it needs not to be connected with adjacent polygons, meaning they should not share any vertices. If you select one face and press v - split, will the result for this polygon be what you want for all polygons?

Comment: I have all polygons split, but this doesn't change the result. See Duarte's answer, displacement always affects the vertices. So the answer to my questions is: No, can't be done. Same is true for sculpting, which I tried next to cope with my problem.

Comment: What about the following idea: Using Python, you could create one vertice at the center of each polygon, so that the vertex can be associated with the poylgon by index. Then after displacing those vertices you can shift the polygon center back to the associated vertice.

Comment: It's not a bad idea. But basically I could also create my own displacement in Python. I think it's too much effort for what I want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Displace is always calculated on a per vertex basis, regardless of what you do, you can separate individual faces, and displace them, but the displacement is still gonna happen on each vertex individually, deforming each face.

Also since most displace textures are "continuous" functions, the faces will still look as a continuous uniform surface as if they were still attached, since the displacement wont introduce any gaps or discontinuities.

You can try and mark all edges of your mesh as sharp, add an *Edge Split* modifier to separate all faces, then apply the displacement to your mesh.

To make the effect more visible you may also add a *smooth modifier*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another way might be to use duplis to put (visible) moving objects at each vertex of the (hidden) deformed mesh.